# Trying to write a javascript slideshow, but the images do not align after awhile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am building this website that contains an image slide show written in javasript. Here is the relevant html.

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="firstelement">
        <div id="leftsidebar"> 
          <img class="leftslide" src="/images/IMG_96768613163825.jpeg">
          <img class="leftslide" src="/images/IMG_96772192197469.jpeg">
          <img class="leftslide" src="/images/IMG_96781303842831.jpeg">
          <img class="leftslide" src="/images/IMG_96785091848819.jpeg">
          <img class="leftslide" src="/images/IMG_96764834500597.jpeg">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="secondelement">
        <div id="slideshow">
          <img class="slide" src="/images/IMG_96764834500597.jpeg">
          <img class="slide" src="/images/IMG_96768613163825.jpeg">
          <img class="slide" src="/images/IMG_96772192197469.jpeg">
          <img class="slide" src="/images/IMG_96781303842831.jpeg">
          <img class="slide" src="/images/IMG_96785091848819.jpeg">
        </div>
      </td>
      <td id="thirdelement">      
        <ul id="announcements"><h3>Announcements</h3>
          <li class="announcement">Announcement #1 - Dates and times could go here, along with a short description of the announcement.</li><hr>
          <li class="announcement">Announcement #2 - These could just be links to pages that have fliers or other representations of the announcements.</li><hr>
          <li class="announcement">Announcement #3 - Could even add images, experiment with fonts, etc.</li><hr>
          <li class="announcement">Announcement #4 - These would change as needed. I am only adding generic text because I am not aware of any current announcements that need posted.</li><hr>
         </ul>
       </td>       
   </tr>
 </table>
```

And here is slideshow.js that makes it run

```
// Global variables
var numslides = 0;
var numleftslides = 0;
var currentslide = 0, oldslide = 4;
var slide1 = 0;
var slide2 = 1;
var slide3 = 2;
var slide4 = 3;
var slide5 = 4;
var x = 0;
var a = 0;
var b = 240;
var c = 480;
var d = 720;
var e = 960;
var picWidth = 0;
var leftPicHeight = 0;
var slides = new Array();
var leftslides = new Array();
function makeSlideShow() {
  // hide the nav bar options
  setupMenu();
  // find all images with the class "slide"
  imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
  for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    if (imgs[i].className != "slide" && imgs[i].className != "leftslide") continue;
    else if (imgs[i].className == "slide" ) {
      slides[numslides] = imgs[i];
      jQuery("#slideshow").css('width', jQuery(slides[numslides]).css('width'));

      // stack images with first slide on top
      if (numslides == 0) {
        imgs[i].style.zIndex = 10;
      }
      else {
        imgs[i].style.zIndex = 0;
      }
      //imgs[i].onclick = nextSlide;
      numslides++;
    }
    else {
      leftslides[numleftslides] = imgs[i];   
      numleftslides++;
    }
  } // end for loop
  nextSlide();
} // end makeSlideShow()
function nextSlide() {
  // Set current slide to be under the new top slide
  slides[currentslide].style.zIndex = 9;
  // Move older slide to the bottom of the stack
  slides[oldslide].style.zIndex = 0;

  oldslide = currentslide;
  currentslide++;

  if (currentslide >= numslides) currentslide = 0;

  // start at the right edge
  picWidth = parseInt(jQuery(slides[currentslide]).css('width'));
  jQuery(slides[currentslide]).css('left', -picWidth + "px");

  x = -picWidth;

  // Move the new slide to the top
  slides[currentslide].style.zIndex = 10;

  if (a < 0) a = 960;
  if (b < 0) b = 960;
  if (c < 0) c = 960;
  if (d < 0) d = 960;
  if (e < 0) e = 960;

  animateSlide();
  window.setTimeout("nextSlide();", 5000); 
}
function animateSlide() {
  // Lower moves slower, higher moves faster
  x = Math.min(0, x + 7);
  a = Math.max(-240, a - 2);
  b = Math.max(-240, b - 2);
  c = Math.max(-240, c - 2);
  d = Math.max(-240, d - 2);
  e = Math.max(-240, e - 2);

  // previous image moves off the left edge
  // (comment the next line for a different effect)
  jQuery(slides[oldslide]).css('left', (x + picWidth) + "px");
  jQuery(slides[currentslide]).css('left', x + "px");

  jQuery(leftslides[slide1]).css('top', a + "px");
  jQuery(leftslides[slide2]).css('top', b + "px");
  jQuery(leftslides[slide3]).css('top', c + "px");
  jQuery(leftslides[slide4]).css('top', d + "px");
  jQuery(leftslides[slide5]).css('top', e + "px");

  // repeat until slide is at zero position
  if (x < 0) window.setTimeout("animateSlide();", 1);
}
// create the slideshow when the page loads
jQuery(document).ready(makeSlideShow);
```

The slideshow actually (sort of) works. In firefox and chrome, while the browser is up, it seems to work fine. When I minimize it, however, and then bring it back up again, the pictures still animate, but they get misaligned. In internet explorer, the images simple don't move fast enough and the timing is all off. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm entering this site in a web contest and I demo it tomorrow afternoon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of providing your code, why not make a jsFiddle that we can actually *see* the issue? Hard to tell what it's doing just by looking at code.

Comment: There are images and a lot to load and I am not familiar enough with jsfiddle to produce all of that, but here is the [site](http://aisatuis.appspot.com/). Notice that when you just stay on the page, everything seems fine, but if you minimize it and bring it back up again, images seem misaligned. Also notice that IE and Opera  don't seem to work well at all. Too slow.

Comment: Awesome, live code is great! Hmmm, it only seems to be every once in a while. How big of an issue is it on your end?

Comment: It's  not that big of a deal. If I stay on the screen and don't touch it, it works just fine. But if I navigate away from the page by doing something like minimizing the browser and then bringing it back up, it starts to malfunction. IE and Opera animate the images so slowly, that they don't seem to work well from the get-go. I can demo it tomorrow if I just keep the page up. But I would prefer to have this fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many toils, I believe I know what the problem is and I found a way to fix it. What I believe may have been happening is that changing the pages focus on and off disturbed the slide show enough so that the calculations for the positioning of the images wasn't keeping up with the display. It's almost like you get into a "race condition" when you do that. So I made everything reset by having the appropriate function trigger with an `window.onfocus(...)` event. This allowed everything to reset if the user left the page and came back, such as in the case of minimizing and restoring the page. Due to IE not loading images fast enough, I placed an `if-statement` to see if the browser was IE and then handle things differently. That seemed to be a good patch. Unfortunately, now I'm realizing that really big screens distort the site and interfere with some functionality. I think I'm going to just have to accept that for now, but if anyone has any suggestions where that is concerned, I'm all ears. Thanks to all who participated in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but this would be too long for a comment:
There are some things you could optimize. E.g. there's no need to get all images by tag name, 
then using a `for`-loop to check every image if it has the class name `slide` 
and then adding it to an array. As you're already using jQuery, you can just fetch all 
slide images using

```
var slides = jQuery.makeArray($(".slide"));
```

I've just added your markup to a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xateL3e6/) (without your script) and added some dummy images and console log messages so it's easy to check what this array contains.

For reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/

Comment: I can appreciate this and I wish I were a more efficient/better code writer. But I am guessing that even if I optimize my code in ways such as this, the problem(s) with the image-animated slideshow would remain.

Comment: @MattCremeens Think so, too, and this was in no way meant to criticize your code as it works well despite of the issues you're actually asking about. Though untested, I think it could increase performance avoiding loops and just fetching the elements you need for the slideshow, and maybe can be of help to reduce future coding by using functionality provided by a library like jquery.